# Invalid MEX-Files

Tags: linux, matlab, compiler-errors, mex

I have compiled and run my Matlab code sucessfully in my computer, but there is something wrong when I run it on annother. The error information as following:

```
bash-3.1# sh /data/release/cli/forecaster_new/forecaster/run_dispatch.sh /usr/local/matlab /data/release/cli/forecaster_new/forecaster/1-1.txt /data/release/cli/forecaster_new/forecaster/1-1.out
------------------------------------------
Setting up environment variables
---
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is .:/usr/local/matlab/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/client:/usr/local/matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64
Warning: This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup
option. For more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the
MATLAB Release Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/bropbi9-1.html#brubkzc-1',
'-browser') 
> In run_predict at 5
??? Invalid MEX-file
'/usr/local/matlab/toolbox/compiler/mcr/compiler/deploywhich.mexa64':
/usr/local/matlab/runtime/glnxa64/libmwopczippackage.so: undefined symbol:
_ZN2fl10filesystem6detail19process_code_traits11to_internalERKSs.

Error in ==> fopen at 16



Error in ==> dlmwrite at 120



Error in ==> run_predict at 71




MATLAB:invalidMEXFile
Warning: 1 invisible figure(s) exist at MCR termination.

If your application has terminated unexpectedly, please note that 
 applications generated by the MATLAB Compiler terminate when there are no 
 visible figure windows. See the documentation for WaitForFiguresToDie and
 WAITFORCALLBACKS for more information.
```

The OS of the compiling computer is Ubuntu 7.10(64-bits)， the Matlab version is Matlab r2010a, and the gcc version is 4.1.3.

Comment: On the MATLAB machine, what is the output of `ver`?  Also on MATLAB machine, run `ldd deploywhich.mexa64` in the OS shell.

Comment: The output of version is R2010a on the MATLAB machine, and after running this command I can see that all libs I need is in the  _/usr/lib64/_

Comment: Do the two computers have the same architecture (esp. 32 vs 64 bit) and same Matlab version? What about compiling the code on the machine where it should run?

Comment: Please post the _exact_ output of version up to and including the like with `Java Version:`.